# Nested Ajax Calls without locking browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making an Ajax call to a CMS but for each value ('site') returned from my Ajax call, I need to list the users who have access ('shares').  I've reproduced below a template of my code.  (I hope that I haven't broken it syntactically by stripping it of proprietary stuff ).

The code actually works.  It's just that because I've had to add a 'synch' of 'false' to the sub call, the browser locks up until everything is complete.  Any DOM manipulation that I've coded doesn't happen until the last 'site' is iterated.  (I can only see that *anything* is going on by using Chrome Dev Tools).

If I don't have the synchronication parameter in then the outer loop iterates too quickly for the inner one to keep up.

Please can someone tell me if there are any better solutions available.

Many thanks.

```
<script>

var mySites
var myShares

mySites = blah({
  path:   'aa/bb/cc/',
  url:        '',
  data:   { method: 'sites.search', limit: 600} 
});   

mySites.done(function(data) { 
  var OutSites = data;  
  console.log(data);  
  var Sites = OutSites.data.sites;
  $.each(Sites, function(key, value) {
    console.log(key, value.uuid, value.description);

    myShares = blah({
      path:         'dd/ee/ff',
      url:        '',
      async: false,
      data:  { method: 'share.getList', target: value.uuid} 
    });


    myShares.done(function(data) { 
      var OutShares = data;
      var ShareUsers = OutShares.data.user;
      if (typeof ShareUsers !== 'undefined') {  
        $.each(ShareUsers, function(key, value) {
          consol.log(key, value.uuid);   
        });
      }    
    });

  });      
});
</script>
```

Comment: And what exactly is `blah`, is that a new form of ajax ?

Comment: Stop using async false and global variables, and your issues will be solved

Comment: `"the outer loop iterates too quickly for the inner one to keep up"` - What does that even mean?

Comment: `myShares` is a global, it's overwritten in each iteration of the loop, so only the last `done()` call is executed

Comment: @adeneo: Then don't make it global.  It's not really clear from this contrived example what the overall goal is, but essentially you should never have to *wait* for an asynchronous operation to complete.  Instead, that operation would have a callback which gets executed after it completes.  Any response to the operation would be invoked in that callback.

Comment: @David - I was just noting what the actual problem with the code was, and what the OP means by *"...iterates too quickly"*, the globals are the real issue here.

Comment: @adeneo: Oh, my bad.  In my haste I thought that was the OP responding to me :)

Comment: The code should look more like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/4bszb78u/

Comment: Thank you all for your input.  Sorry about the 'blah'; I was just stripping my code of all proprietary stuff.

Comment: I hadn't appreciated the globalness of myShares.  I will rebuild my code from the linked example and remove the asynch false.
NB In my efforts to slim down my example code, I removed my DOM manipulation.  Building a nice HTML table of my data was my goal but I'd like to see it 'being built' in the browser so that at least my users can appreciate that something is happening.
When I didn't have the asynch false, it felt like the outer loop had run multiple times whilst the inner loop had only run once but I suspect that the global variable was more the problem.
I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: Hi I tried to rebuild my code from the example but I couldn't use $ajax function because it is already embedded in an object provided by the CMS API.  My code is at
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/spiralling/ek6893ra/)

My output is below.  It should alternate between the site info and the user info and the users should be different. How can I resolve without using asynch: false?.

Site: 56211
Site: 7B626
Site: 8B94D
Site: 8E027
Site: 91009
Site: FAA06
User for 56211: DD35F
User for 7B626: DD35F
User for 8B94D: DD35F
User for FAA06: DD35F
User for 91009: DD35F
User for 8E027: DD35F

Comment: Ignore last comment.  Pasted wrong code.

Comment: OK.  The penny's dropped.  I've finally got it.  I'm not sure I can even put my misunderstanding into words but I'll try.  It doesn't matter what order things run in, I just need to pass parent variables down and then just do my output after the lowest level call.
I was trying to say 'site is..' then make an ajax call to get info about the site and output that but asynchronicity means that comes out in the wrong order.  I simply needed to pass the site name down the chain and output all the info together at the end.  My accidental globals weren't helping either.  Thanks everyone.